# select record in one table that are not in another with a pattern match

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I would like to find all records in the column of one table that are not in a column of another. I can do so with this query:

```
SELECT
    kywd
FROM
    from_client
WHERE
    kywd NOT IN
        (SELECT
            kywd
        FROM
            from_me);
```

However, I would like to extend this to allow for some pattern matching. At the very least I'd like to see if the `from_client` `kywd` appears anywhere in the `from_me` `kywd`. So, like, `'%kywd%'`. I tried ...`WHERE '%' || kywd || '%' NOT IN`... as a wild guess, and a result set was actually returned, but I suspect this syntax is just gibberish.

How can I make this select statement allow for these wildcards?

Comment: Is this a one-time operation, or is performance important?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Just one time! Can be as inefficient necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not exists` is likely to be faster than join

```
select kywd
from from_client
where not exists (
    select 1
    from from_me
    where position(from_client.kywd, kywd) > 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT from_client.kywd
FROM from_client
LEFT JOIN from_me
  ON from_client.kywd LIKE '%' || from_me.kywd || '%'
WHERE from_me.kywd IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines.

```
SELECT
    kywd
FROM
    from_client
LEFT OUTER JOIN from_me ON 
from_client.kywd like from_me.kywd -- replace with whatever appropriate
WHERE
from_me.some_id IS NULL
```

By "replace with whatever appropriate", I mean:

`from_client.kywd LIKE '%' || from_me.kywd || '%'`

or

`from_me.kywd LIKE '%' || from_client.kywd || '%'`

or any other condition which is appropriate there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [EXCEPT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html) statement. In you scenarion it would be something like

```
 SELECT kywd
 FROM  from_client
 --WHERE <Conditions here>
 except
 SELECT kywd
 FROM  from_me
 --WHERE <Conditions here>
```

and returns what exists in from_client that does not exists in from_me.